# Get Youtbe Videos in a list

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I have youtube account I need to retrieve all the videos in that accound , I have generated api key. I am getting single videos by giving the video Id and api key. how do I retrieve all the videos in the account ?

Comment: You should get the uploaded playlist Id, then use playlistItems.list method.
Here it explains in detail: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#videos-retrieve-uploads

Answer (score 0):

You would make a search request and specify the channelID of the account.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: this is the way we strongly discourage. Right way is below, search is really inefficient when you already know the channelId, hence a search request costs 100 quotas now.

Comment: Unless the videos are not in a playlist, hence the search.

Comment: videos will be in the uploaded playlist as long as they are public, if they are not public, they won't be available in search either.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention a playlist, why do you keep referring to one?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads